# Can WCF keep reference equality over the wire?

Tags: c#, wcf, reference

Say you have a few classes defined as

```
[DataContract]
public class Foo
{
    [DataMember]
    public List<Bar> Bars {get; set;}
}

[DataContract]
public class Bar
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Baz { get; set; }
}

public class Service1 : IService1
{
    public bool Send(Foo foo)
    {
        var bars = foo.Bars;

        bars[0].Baz = "test2";
        return bars[0].Baz == bars[1].Baz;
    }
}

[ServiceContract]
public interface IService1
{
    [OperationContract]
    bool Send(Foo composite);
}
```

Assuming I am using WCF to WCF with a shared data contract DLL between the client and server, if I do something like the following

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    using (var client = new ServiceReference.Service1Client())
    {
        var bar = new Bar();
        bar.Baz = "Start";

        List<Bar> bars = new List<Bar>();
        bars.Add(bar);
        bars.Add(bar);

        var foo = new Foo();
        foo.Bars = bars;

        Console.WriteLine(bars[0].Baz == bars[1].Baz);

        bars[0].Baz = "test1";
        Console.WriteLine(bars[0].Baz == bars[1].Baz);

        Console.WriteLine(client.Send(foo));

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

}
```

I get `True`, `True`, `False` as my result which means that `bars[0]` and `bars[1]` did not point to the same object on the server.

Am I doing something wrong, or is it impossible to have shared references over WCF?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to [explicitly tell WCF to preserve references](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractattribute.isreference.aspx) by specifying

```
[DataContract(IsReference = true)]
```

otherwise reference equality is lost during message construction.

Comment: What would I need to do to make the code above use `BinaryFormatter`?

Comment: I can not tell how to use `BinaryFormatter` without trying it myself. But you can - if you did not already - try using `BinaryMessageEncoding`, that might preserve reference equality, too, but I do not know for sure.

Comment: I was wrong, this won't work because WCF first builds a message and only then serializes it using the specified serializer. But at this point the references have already been lost by default so using a reference preserving serializer will not help. But there is still a solution, you can instruct WCF to preserve references when building the message - see the updated answer.

Comment: Thanks, I changed `Bar` to use `IsRefrence=true` and now I get `True`,`True`,`True`.

Answer (score 2):

The `DataContact` annotations indicate serialization.  That is, your object is serialized, passed over the wire, and then re-constituted as a new object on the other end.  So no, it's not possible to keep reference equality.

Note that also, presumably, your WCF service is running on a different machine, or at least a different process.  So the WCF service and client normally won't even have access to the same memory space, which means that sharing a reference between them is not practical in theory.

Comment: The way you phrase it I could use something other than `[DataContract]` to be able to do it. What would I need to do instead? EDIT: per your last update, I don't care about client and server sharing a reference, all I want is two objects sent in the same message to still show reference equality on the other side.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain no, because it has to be serialized one way or the other -- that's the only way the object can get passed to the other side.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain put another way, if there was no serialization, then there would be no need for WCF -- you could just pass the client a reference to the memory address.

Comment: I think you don't understand what I am asking. I agree with you that a reference between client and server can not be shared, what I want to know is if I send a single object referenced in two locations in a single message is it possible to get a single object referenced in two locations on the other side. Doing that is very possible with serialization, you just store the references separate from the values.