# Can you add an object to multiple parent objects in a Web Service?

Tags: .net, web-services, wcf

If I have a Product object and a Customer object and I want to add an Order child object to both parent objects, will that relationship persist over a SOAP web service call?  Or will the receiving service view the Order as two separate objects - one in Product and one in Customer?  Or will it view it as one unique object that has two parent objects and keep those relationships?

The receiving service is WCF, if that matters, but it shouldn't matter what the client language is since it will have to work regardless.

So, for example if I pass in the objects with this relationship:

```
Product          Customer
   \_____ Order ____/
```

After it's passed to the web service will it still look like the above or will it now look like the below?

```
Product          Customer
   |                |
 Order            Order
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOAP does, or at least can, preserve object identity.

Comment: Great, thanks!  I just didn't want to make massive edits to my service if it was already known not to work across SOAP for some reason.

Comment: After testing this, it doesn't seem to work - is there a trick to this?

Comment: You may have to enable this behavior, see for example [here how to do it in WCF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21639216/can-wcf-keep-reference-equality-over-the-wire).

Comment: BOOM!!  That was the ticket!